# Navigating a JSON Array with Newtonsoft JRaw

Tags: json.net

Is it possible for me to navigate a JSON array using the [JRaw Class](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JRaw.htm)?

Messing around with it in [Linqpad](https://www.linqpad.net/), I'm not sure how I'd be able to extract the datetime strings in the two objects contained in the json array:

```
string payload = @"[
    {
        ""measureTime"": ""2019-10-19T14:43:00.8183732Z"",
        ""sensor1"": 342.0,
        ""sensor2"": 32.0,
        ""sensor3"": 0.0324,
        ""sensor4"": -893.438
    },
    {
        ""measureTime"": ""2019-10-19T19:43:00.7473732Z"",
        ""sensor1"": 348.0,
        ""sensor2"": 32.0,
        ""sensor3"": 0.0324,
        ""sensor4"": -893.438
    }
]";


JRaw raw = new JRaw(payload);
raw.HasValues.Dump();
raw.Next.Dump();
raw.Children().Dump();
```

The output of those dumps are:

`False`

`null`

`(0 items)`

---

For context, I'm trying to use Azure API Management to examine the json contained in the body of an incoming request, and verify that all the datetime strings contained in it comport to [RFC3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339#section-5.6)'s date-time format. This would be very simple if I could just do:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(context.Request.Body.As<string>(preserveContent: true),
                                                        new JsonSerializerSettings {DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None});
```

However, 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings' is [not currently supported within APIM policy expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policy-expressions#CLRTypes)

If I just use JArray.Parse(), that resulting JArray has the datetime string stored in a DateTime object, rather than the original string, which means I can't validate the format of the string as it originally came in.

I do have access to the JRaw class, and thought I might be able to make use of that somehow.

Comment: [`JRaw`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JRaw.cs) inherits from [`JValue`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JValue.cs).  It just wraps a JSON string literal without parsing or interpreting it.

Comment: Ah ha, that's why those methods are there. Want to write this as an answer @dbc?